# Error FilesystemIterator en Laravel

Tags: laravel

trabajando en mi proyecto fui a abrir una de las vistas y me mostro el siguiente error

```
FilesystemIterator::__construct C:\xampp\htdocs\sis_control\storage\framework/cache/data\de, - El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada. (code: 3)
```

Ejecute en mi consola de comandos las los siguientes comandos una vez que había refrescado con `F5` la vista y el error había desaparecido:

```
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan view:clear
```

Pero me gustaría si me pudiera explicar porque despues de un tiempo trabajando en mi proyecto salta este error?

Comment: que vista era como la tienes configurada?

Comment: es una vista donde muestro las salvas de base de datos que le he realizado con mi sistema